# how can i host a regular website and a python flask web app at the same time using apache

Tags: server, python, apache2

Ok so the title might be a little confusing but, basically i'm trying to keep my normal website as

`www.website.com` but also be able to easily deploy any python flask web app on say `www.website.com/flaskapp`

is there any way i could do that?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181364/running-a-flask-website-in-a-subdirectory-with-apache

That said - I'd recommend to host your flask app via a subdomain, eg. `flaskapp.website.com` - this makes it easier to maintain.